# Android change preference value and updating display in preference screen

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

I am a new Android developer and I've got my first app nearly complete.

One of the last things I have on my list of things to do is Tasker integration. I have the integration working up to a point.

My app is currently setup to work as a plugin and accept a string from tasker and update a preference with the new string. This is working.

The problem is when I relaunch my app, the value of the preference isn't updating. I can't get the preference summary to update until I completely close the app and relaunch it.

So the question is, how do I force my app to reload the preferences from within the app's onResume or is there a better way all together?

This is the code from the receiver that updates the preference value:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String album_name = bundle.getString(PluginBundleManager.BUNDLE_EXTRA_STRING_MESSAGE);
prefs.edit().putString("text_default_album", StringUtil.sanitize(album_name)).commit();
Log.d(TAG, "fr: "+prefs.getString("text_default_album", ""));
```

This is the in the activity's onResume:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String album_name = prefs.getString("text_default_album", "");
Log.d(TAG, "album_name: "+album_name);

final Preference album = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("text_default_album");
album.setSummary(album_name);
```

The manifest declaration for the receiver:

```
    <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.FireReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":background"
            tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver" >

        <!-- this Intent filter allows the plug-in to discovered by Locale -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.twofortyfouram.locale.intent.action.FIRE_SETTING" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**UPDATE:** For anyone who may run into this question and be struggling to figure it out, once I removed the `android:process=":background"` in the AndroidManifest.xml declaration of the receiver. It now works as expected.

Comment: To anyone who is searching for how to update one preference when another changes, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603633/updating-preferences-in-real-time.

Answer (score 0):

Commit saves the new value in the storage but it doesn't update the one in memory. If you want this functionality you should use apply. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29)

So you must replace

```
prefs.edit().putString("text_default_album", StringUtil.sanitize(album_name)).commit();
```

with

```
prefs.edit().putString("text_default_album", StringUtil.sanitize(album_name)).apply();
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: That didn't force the preference to update either. When i went back to the preference activity it was still showing the old value. Both worked the same when I closed my app and relaunched it.

Comment: @Jayrox This is strange, the only thing I can think of to replace SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()); in your activity with SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); I read somewhere that getApplicationContext() returns a different context than the activity. Give it a try I don't know what else may be...

Comment: that doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: @Jayrox OK It seems that you have a problem similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098981/sharedpreferences-in-broadcastreceiver-seems-to-not-update) or to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465318/broadcast-receiver-not-affecting-shared-preferences-in-android-4-0-probably-3-1) the only diff between your app and mine (which is working as expected) is that I do not use a broadcast receiver to update sharedpreferences, I do it in an activity...

Comment: i've added the manifest receiver code to the original question

Comment: I just removed the `android:process=":background"` code and now it works as I expected. Thanks!

Comment: @Jayrox There is a drawback, now your receiver runs on the main thread so keep the onReceive as small as possible...

Comment: I figure that would be fine for my usage. All it does is grab the intent, trim the string, sanitize out illegal path characters and save the preference. A majority of the time my app is in the background. However, others who may run into this question may want to be a little more cautious.

Comment: -1: *"Commit saves the new value in the storage but it doesn't update the one in memory"* - that can't be true. If it was, then every *get* of a preference would be forced to go to storage. This would completely defeat the purpose of having an in-memory copy.

Comment: does not work. the only difference between apply and commit is that apply is asynchronous.